# android: put window custom titlebar controls in a seperate class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo, android-titlebar

I followed an online tutorial teaching how to build a custom title bar in android.
After you build the layout, here is how to add it onto an activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
... 
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

And if you add onClickListeners on the buttons which are part of the titlebar, you do this:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MyApp.this, News.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This has to be done everytime you want to add a titlebar to an activity.

Is there a way to create a class for the titlebar and throw all in there so I dont have to repeat myself on each activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you most probably trying to do is an [action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Please take a look at this question [What is the equivalent of ActionBar in earlier sdk versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031774/what-is-the-equivalent-of-actionbar-in-earlier-sdk-versions) to find out how to do it for an earlier sdk.