# Android Actionbar

Tags: android

I have a pretty simple question about the Android ActionBar... is this intended to be present in the app, to use as a sort of header, or is it only intended to show when the user hits the setting button on the device?

I'm trying to implement a menu that is always present in the app, like a logo for branding, and some other actions, like a search icon and perhaps a map icon to see the map functionality. Any suggestions? Also see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825274/custom-header-menu-in-android-app-how-to)

Comment: could you add a part of the code you already done to try that ?

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar is always displayed. Check out the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) for more information on the ActionBar UI patterns and usage.

You can use the excellent [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to provide an ActionBar on 2.x devices.

The ActionBar sounds perfect for the branding/icons you want. You would use your logo as the icon, and then have Action Items for Search and Map functionality.

Comment: thanks for that comment. mine is not always showing, it only shows when i hit the settings button on the phone. wondering if i'm missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your **android:targetSdkVersion** to 11 or more ? [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) is available only for Honeycomb and ICS :)