# Android - Display menu without title bar or having menu button

Tags: java, android, menu

How can I display a menu in my application when I don't have a hardware menu button on my phone and when I hide the titlebar?

Comment: The usage of menu is deprecated since 3.0, use an [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) instead.

Comment: The problem is, my minSDKVersion is 8, so I can't use ActionBar

Comment: How about using the support library ? or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867617/how-do-i-use-the-actionbar-on-older-versions-of-android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your question: you can open the menu programmatically using `openOptionsMenu()`.

However, you probably should include a ActionBar instead, as suggested in the comments.