# ActionBar - Android Tablet 2.3 and 4.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, compatibility, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Am working on a Android application that target tablets running both 2.3 and 4.0 so I need to support both these versions.

I found the support library to support fragments but how can I use ActionBar taken that its only available in Android 3.0+ and not in 2.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you can also use ActionBarCompat library from Android Support package. It's v7 version now supports [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html). Android dev team published a really useful introduction video video about [using ActionBarCompat](http://youtu.be/6TGgYqfJnyc)

Answer (score 3):

Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It requires very little work on your part and is well maintained.

Also see: [What is the equivalent of ActionBar in earlier sdk versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031774/what-is-the-equivalent-of-actionbar-in-earlier-sdk-versions)