# How to create a ActionBar in Android 2.2 version?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new in Android programming. I just wanna how to create a ActionBar for android 2.2 version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of ActionBar in earlier sdk versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031774/what-is-the-equivalent-of-actionbar-in-earlier-sdk-versions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ActionBarSherlock`. It's an open source library that emulates the exact features and design of the `ActionBar`.

Please see: http://actionbarsherlock.com

Google uses this as well in a number of applications.

Comment: when I edit the minSdk version like the minSdk version of the project is 15 and the target is 15, is there a possibility that when I edit it .. it run on 2.2 version????

Answer (score 2):

yes ActionBarSherlock is best option,

Please See https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: is the link a sample for android 2.2 version?? because many projects i download in ActionBarSherlock is for 4.0 version or higher

Comment: Android 4.0 already have ActionBar, and whatever you have downlaoded that is not only for android 4.0, check the mainfest file for minSdk

Comment: ohh thank you  by the way how to import the file in the site in Eclipse that you gave??? because when I importing the file no project appear...

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompat` library from `com.android.support`.

> Google has released com.android.support to support things like this on older devices

Add the dependecy in build.gradle (it's **NOT** in the root directory) inside `dependencies{...}`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

And change your theme to `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.AppCompat.*` (The wildcard represents more styles inside `Theme.AppCompat`